# SQL Query to get column result conditionally based on column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Below is my SQL Table,

[image]

how do i get the result from this table as pack_cd and date which is not null. e.g.

[image]

from SQL Table i want to get `PACK_CD` and date as

- `ETDT` if its `NOT NULL`
- `PPDT` if `ETDT IS NULL` and `PPDT` is `NOT NULL`
- `PDT` if `ETDT IS NULL` and `PPDT` is `NULL` and `PDT` is `NOT
  NULL`

Comment: Are you familiar with `CASE`? This seems like a good use case for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT
    PACK_CD,
    DATE = COALESCE(ETDT, PPDT, PDT)
FROM [YourTable]
```

If you want to show only those rows with `NULL` column, just add a `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE
    ETDT IS NULL
    OR PPDT IS NULL
    OR PDT IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

This is alternate option to understand. The same you achieve COALESCE as @wewesthemenace suggested.

```
SELECT
    PACK_CD,
    DATE = case when isnull(ETDT,'') != '' then ETDT 
                else 
                    case when isnull(PPDT,'') != '' then PPDT 
                    else
                        PDT
                    end
                end             
FROM [YourTable]
```